# Adjust Threshold Within Macro ImageJ

Tags: imagej, image-thresholding, fiji

I'm looking to write a macro which requires user input to segment kidneys through thresholding. I'm currently running this:

```
selectWindow("Cortex");
//run("Threshold...");
title = "WaitForUserDemo";
msg = "If necessary, use the \"Threshold\" tool to\nadjust the threshold, then click \"OK\".";
waitForUser(title, msg);
```

While the thresholding colour appears, there is no option here to adjust the threshold as the user. Does anyone know how I can get the user to be able to adjust the threshold without having to click "Image -> Adjust - > threshold" each time?

Thanks!

Comment: If I run your code with the line `run("Threshold...");` uncommented, it works as you expect. The Threshold window appears for user adjustment. This is running latest Fiji/ImageJ1.52p.

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you